# Errors thrown on Meteor server methods dont log original stack trace

Tags: meteor

Since upgrading to `meteor 1.8.0.2` from 1.6.x I've noticed that any method call that results in an error is printed on the server console as:

```
Exception while invoking method 'login' [object Object]
Exception while invoking method 'customMethodByMe' [object Object]
```

This happens both on development on my mac and deployed on Galaxy.

Before, the whole stack trace was printed, but this Object object logging doesnt help me figure out the actual problem. My solution so far has been to wrap method implementation in a try catch statement that logs the original exception and rethrows it for the client to know.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'customMethodByMe'() {
    try {
      return customMethodByMeImpl();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      throw e;
    }
  }
});
```

In this case, since the error is on the `login` method which is in a package, I cannot update it to print the real problem. On the client, all I get on any error is that there was a 500 error on the server, so no root cause either.

```
{"isClientSafe":true,"error":500,"reason":"Internal server error","message":"Internal server error [500]","errorType":"Meteor.Error"}
```

Any ideas on how to temporarly solve this? I've been searching for a server level error handler but so far have found nothing.

thanks

Comment: You should probably be able to use a local version of the accounts package (copy it in a "/packages" folder at the root of your Meteor project).

Answer (score 0):

I did not get to experience this directly, but when I need to print an object, I usually use JSON.stringfy.

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'customMethodByMe'() {
    try {
      return customMethodByMeImpl();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
      throw e;
    }
  }
});
```

This should resolve so that you can at least read the error log.